# Why is `RLock` necessary in Golang?

Tags: go, concurrency, locking

In my first glance at `sync.RWMutex` in **Go**, `RLock` is unnecessary: one may just treat the critical block as sequential code.

What is the reason behind `RLock`? I see the following in the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/sync):

> In the terminology of the Go memory model, the n'th call to Unlock “synchronizes before” the m'th call to Lock for any n < m, just as for Mutex. For any call to RLock, there exists an n such that the n'th call to Unlock “synchronizes before” that call to RLock, and the corresponding call to RUnlock “synchronizes before” the n+1'th call to Lock.

Could anyone explain this to me in detail?

Comment: `RLock` is the "read lock" as opposed to `Lock` which is the "read+write lock".

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex) explains the purpose of RWMutex:

> The lock can be held by an arbitrary number of readers or a single writer.

The [RLock](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex.RLock) and [RUnlock](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex.RUnlock) methods are necessary to distinguish a caller that locks the mutex for read from a caller that locks the mutex for write.